# unsportsmanly conduct

Tags: adjectives

Suppose an athlete commits a bad foul on one of the opposite team's players during a football match. He injures that player's leg severely. You know that he did it deliberately! Then I was wondering if the following adjective fits the sentence:

> - I didn't like his **unsportsmanly** conduct during the competition.

Can the above adjective convey this meaning that what he did was not what a real sportsman does?

Comment: *Unsportsmanly* is a valid word, but the more common term in US English is *[unsportsmanlike conduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsportsmanlike_conduct)*

Comment: Yes @stangdon. It was exactly why I asked about it; I hoped somebody offer the adjective 'unsportsmanlike'. Thank you very much. It was helpful.

Comment: I'm going to make this an answer, since it seems to be all that's needed.

Comment: *Reckless* and *cynical* come to mind, typically used with *challenge*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Unsportsmanly* is a grammatically correct word, but it's not a very common word.

**Unsportsmanlike** is a much more commonly used term.  As you can see from Google Ngrams, unsportsmanly has never been very common compared to unsportsmanlike or unsporting: [unsportsmanly vs unsportsmanlike vs unsporting](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unsportsmanly%2Cunsportsmanlike%2Cunsporting&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunsportsmanly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunsportsmanlike%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunsporting%3B%2Cc0)

You will find the term "unsportsmanlike conduct" used in the rulebooks of the [National Football League](http://www.nfl.com/static/content/public/image/rulebook/pdfs/15_Rule12_Player_Conduct.pdf):

> **Section 3 : Unsportsmanlike Conduct**
>   Article 1 : There shall be no unsportsmanlike conduct. This applies to any act which is contrary to the
>   generally understood principles of sportsmanship.

and the [National Hockey League](http://www.nhl.com/nhl/en/v3/ext/rules/2014-2015-rulebook.pdf):

> **Rule 75 – Unsportsmanlike Conduct**
>   75.1 Unsportsmanlike Conduct – Players and non-playing Club
>   personnel are responsible for their conduct at all times and must
>   endeavor to prevent disorderly conduct before, during or after the
>   game, on or off the ice and any place in the rink.

Another possibility is **unsporting conduct** or **unsporting behavior**, which is used by [FIFA](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/affederation/federation/81/42/36/lotg_en.pdf):

> **Cautions for unsporting behaviour**
>    There are different circumstances when a player must be cautioned
>   for unsporting behaviour...

Comment: To the BrE posters out there, is **unsportsmanlike** or **unsporting** more commonly used?  **Unsporting** sounds very British to my ear, but I know that it is widely used.  North AmE definitely favors unsportsmanlike.  (Great answer, just looking for regional clarity.)

Comment: Thank you very much @stangdon; just please tell me if it applies to 'sportsmanlike' and 'sportsmanly' or not.

Comment: @A-friend - "sportsmanlike" and "sportsmanly" are both perfectly valid words, although uncommon ones.